# Weird eclipse compilation error with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm getting this weird compilation error with eclipse  in the following code block. I've included the necessary jars and also tried restarting eclipse but no avail.

```
 public class ControlServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
ResourceBundle rb1;// error on this line
rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControlServlet.class);
```

The error message displayed is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token ";", , expected
- Watchpoint:ControlServlet [access and 
 modification] - rb1.
```

Any idea why this could be happening ? And how I could work around this would be helpful.

Comment: Why is the definition and assignment for `rb1` split across two lines? I am not at all sure that is valid outside of a method (or some other kind of block).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting this error because you can not write assignment statement and declaration as 2 statements in a class (outside of any <del>method or static</del> block with class variables).

So your error is actually on this statement:

```
rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");
```

You <del>can not write such a statement in class without surrounding static/method block.</del> cannot write outside of any method or any initialization block (static or non-static). So you have to combine your 2 statements into 1 like:

```
ResourceBundle rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");
```

Comment: You can write those statements inside non-static blocks too. Therefore I think this should be corrected as "cannot write outside of any method or any initialization block (static or non-static)".

Answer (score 6):

You may have to replace this

```
ResourceBundle rb1;// error on this line
rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");
```

with this

```
ResourceBundle rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");
```

In Java,  we can only have variable declaration statements, an initialization block(static and non-static),  and method defintions inside a class directly. All other statements like assignment statements, control statements, etc., must be inside an initialization block or inside a method definition.

Here, `rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");` is an assignment statement, which is not permitted to put directly inside a class. That is why, we have to combine the declaration, and assignment statements to one like `ResourceBundle rb1 = ResourceBundle.getBundle("connection_config");`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you want to add *why* that is the case. Teach a man to fish, don't just give him one.

Comment: @BrianRoach Thanks for good criticism. I updated my answer. +1 for the comment.